# If $f^2$ is analytic and $f$ is continuous, show that $f$ is also analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, winding-number

Suppose $f^2$ is analytic in a domain $\Omega$ and $f$ is continuous in $\Omega$, show that $f$ is also analytic in $\Omega$.

I know several solutions already exist here but there is one part of a proof that confuses me so I will sketch out the proof and highlight where I am confused.

Proof: Let $g = f^2$. If $g$ is identically zero then the result is clear. So assume $g$ is not identically zero. Then its zeros must be isolated and thus the zeros of $f = {g}^{1/2}$ are isolated. Let $z_0 \in \Omega$ such that $g(z_0) \neq 0$. Then there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $z_0$ such that $g$ is non-zero in $U$ and hence we can define its analytic square root in $U$ which shows that $f = g^{1/2}$ is analytic at every $z_0$ such that $g(z_0) \neq 0$.

Now here is the part that confuses me: If $z_0$ is a zero of $g$ then we can define the square root in a continuous way that winds around the zero so that after a full circle, we get back to the same branch we started with. I think the reasoning behind this is because if we let $\gamma: [0,1] \rightarrow \Omega$ be a path around $z_0$ then from what was said above, if $z_1 \in \gamma$ we can define $f_1 = g^{1/2}$ in a neighborhood $U_1$ of $z_1$. Then for $z_2 \in \gamma$ sufficiently close to $z_1$ we can define $f_2 = g^{1/2}$ in a neighborhood $U_2$ of $z_2$ such that $U_1 \cap U_2 \neq \emptyset$. Since $f_1$ and $f_2$ agree on the intersection of $U_1$ and $U_2$, by the identity theorem we see that $f_2$ is just an analytic extension of $f_1$. Since $\gamma$ is compact, we can cover it with finitely many $U_k$. Then by continuity, we must have that $f_1(\gamma(0)) = f_k(\gamma(1))$. Ok, so if that is all correct, why is this enough to justify that $f = g^{1/2}$ is analytic at the zeros of $g$?

Some of my details may not be correct so please let me know if I made an error.

Comment: Also the argument that $f$ is analytic outside the zeroes of $g$ is not complete as there are two square roots locally and one needs to use continuity to insure $f$ is indeed one of those analytic square roots, so there is no mixing if you wish; this is the crux of the matter as then the result follows trivially since the isolated singularities of $f$ are removable by continuity so no need for complicated arguments with winding numbers etc

Comment: Do you mean that continuity should be used to insure that the same branch of the square root is chosen in each neighborhood of $z$ with $g(z) \neq 0$? And then continuity can be used again to show $f$ is locally bounded at each 0 so they are removable singularities.

Comment: yes - continuity is essential for the fact that $f$ is one branch in a given neighborhood of $w, g(w) \ne 0$; apriori one could have $f$ take values on both branches; then as noted the result follows since $f$ is continuous at its isolated singularities hence is analytic (analyticity is a local property so proving $f$ analytic near any $w$ as above is enough, no need to check anything else, but that fact which seems obvious requires a careful proof and is the essence of the result)

Comment: That is much simpler than what I was doing, thanks!

Comment: happy to be of help

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not enough, otherwise just let $g(z)=z$ and you have constructed a holomorphic square-root of $z$ around $0$!

You need to use the fact that $g$ was defined to be $f^2$ so $g\circ\gamma$ has even winding number about $0$ as $\gamma$ circles around $z_0$ once.